# Do FAANG companies use code templates and generation for services and what do they use?

Tags: templates, code-generation

If you are a company with coding standards, and you want certain types of services to have the same structure, it seems like you would want a template for certain service types. For example, maybe you would have a template to create a skeleton gRPC service in a docker image, complete with IaC and CI/CD workflows.

My question is - is this something that FAANG companies do and if so is there a particular technology for defining templates and generating code that they use?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about the state of the industry rather than presenting a specific programming problem. If you remove the "how do other companies do this?" part, it may work on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Valid, but the community at softwarenegineering is even more difficult than the one here.